# Splitting npm scripts into multiple files

Tags: node.js, npm, browserify, node-sass

is there a way to split npm scripts into multiple files?

Currently I have next structure:

`"pages-build-js": "browserify pages/dev/js/init.js -o pages/static/js/bundle.js",`
`"pages-build-scss": "node-sass pages/dev/scss/init.scss > pages/static/css/main.css",`

However, is there a way, I can move these scripts in separate `package.json` in `pages` directory and then to run it from parent directory?

The problem is that when I make it, looks like it doesn’t see any local packages from parent directory. How can I solve it?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this is what you want but I had a project where we had a separate `package.json` for our backend.

To set everything up we hat this in our main `package.json`

```
"scripts": {
    "setup": "npm install && cd ./src/backend && npm install"
},
```

Which install all packages from the two files.

You should also be able to run other npm scripts that way

So something like this

```
"scripts": {
    "build-js": "cd ./pages && npm run pages-build-js"
},
```